# Characterizations of amenable groups which use the space $\ell_1(G)$ and convolution

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, fourier-analysis, big-list, amenability

Let $G$ be a discrete group.

> Do you know characterizations of amenable groups which use the space $\ell_1(G)$ and convolution?

I only know Johnson's theorem:

> A group is amenable if and only if the Banach algebra $\ell_1(G)$ is amenable.

Different characterizations are welcome.

Comment: I think this needs to be community wiki

Comment: @YemonChoi, your patience has been rewarded after less than 11 years!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like the following characterization, due to Kaimanovich and Vershik (conjectured by Furstenberg):

> A (countable) group is amenable if and only if there is an everywhere positive $\ell^{1}$-function $\mu$ of norm $1$ on $G$ such that $\|g\mu^{\ast n} - \mu^{\ast n}\|_{1} \to 0$ for all $g \in G$.

As a consequence, a group is amenable if and only if some Poisson boundary $\Gamma{(G,\mu)}$ is reduced to a point. The neat thing is that you can always choose a Reiter sequence formed by the convolution powers of a single probability.

Answer (score 6):

To get the ball rolling: the convolution algebra $\ell^1(G)$ always supports a character $\varepsilon$ (=homomorphism from the algebra to the complex numbers) defined by sending $\delta_x$ to 1 for each $x\in G$ - this is usually called the augmentation character - and its kernel is called the augmentation ideal. Denoting this ideal by $I_0(G)$, we have the following result:

**Theorem.** The following are equivalent:

1. $G$ is amenable
2. $I_0(G)$ has a bounded approximate identity
3. $I_0(G)$ has an approximate identity

Another variant of this result is that $G$ is amenable if and only if the one-dimensional $\ell^1(G)$-module corresponding to $\varepsilon$ is flat in the sense of Helemskii et al.

Comment: @Yemon: Can the approximate unit of $I_0(G)$ be taken to be two-sided and of norm at most one?

Comment: Theo: I think that if $G$ is amenable then the BAI can indeed be chosen to have the properties you describe, but I would have to check this. Conversely, the existence of any approximate identity (possibly unbounded) does force $G$ to be amenable; if I recall correctly this is due to George Willis but I will have to check later.

Comment: Good point, Andreas. I wasn't thinking clearly when I said that one could get a BAI of norm 1, this seems to fail for any finite group with cardinality $\geq 3$. (What I *meant* in my head was that 1 minus the BAI has norm 1, via Folner sets as you say.)

Comment: Yemon: I suspect Willis proved 3 $\Rightarrow$ 2, right?

Comment: Theo: yes, I can't remember the exact reference. If I have some time later I will try to update the answer to give references

Comment: Theo: You are right; sorry. I removed my remark. So what is the approximate unit?

Comment: Yemon: Thank you. Don't waste your time looking for it, I'll find it, should I ever need it.

Comment: I've now found a reference: Delaporte-Derighetti, http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1301019
Essentially they proceed as I outlined an hour ago. Their Theorem 3 can be applied in our situation with $H=G$ and shows that a two-sided approximate unit of norm two can indeed be found. If $G$ is infinite, their Theorem 5 shows that $2$ is the best possible bound.